# Is there a command to scan my network and check the conflict IPs

Tags: networking, command-line, scripts

It's hard job to find the duplicate IP when this happens. You know you have then to search all network IPs to check the duplicate. So is there a command line or a script to do that for me?

Comment: Why not set up a DHCP server to hand out IP unique addresses, and prevent the problem? That is why DHCP was invented.

Answer (score 3):

After googling and trying I have found this work around.

Install `arp-scan` if you are not already:

```
sudo apt-get install arp-scan
```

now run this command:

```
sudo arp-scan -l
```

This will search the whole network for duplicate IPs. When two Ips are the same a keyword(DUP) beside the ouput line will be shown and thus you can know the duplicates:

```
% arp-scan -N -r 1 -s 192.168.1.40 192.168.1.0/24
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.2 (ether-scan-engine 1.3) with 256 hosts
192.168.1.33    00:00:5e:00:01:ca       USC INFORMATION SCIENCES INST
192.168.1.34    00:0b:46:e4:8d:6d       Cisco
192.168.1.34    00:0b:48:5d:4c:3f       Cisco (DUP: 2) **DUPLICATE HERE note the mark DUP beside**
192.168.1.45    00:0a:b7:9b:b7:7a       Cisco Systems
192.168.1.46    00:0a:b7:9b:b7:01       Cisco Systems
```